# Acumatica - Adding Multiple Tracking Numbers in Field

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am adding the Tracking Number data field from SOPackageDetail to the Invoices screen (SO303000) on the Freight Details Tab. I know that it only shows one ShipmentNbr and this is what I'm using to join the two tables but I would like all of the tracking numbers, since there can be more than one per shipment number, to show in the field instead of just one. They can be just separated in the field value by a comma. Here is my code and it does work for just one tracking number.
Graph:

```
public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
protected void SOFreightDetail_RowSelecting(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e, PXRowSelecting del)
    {
       if (del != null)
                del(cache, e);

            var row = (SOFreightDetail)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;

            using (new PXConnectionScope())
                {

                    SOPackageDetail track = PXSelect<SOPackageDetail, Where<SOPackageDetail.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOFreightDetail.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base, row.ShipmentNbr);
                    if(track != null){
                      SOFreightDetailExt invoiceExt = row.GetExtension<SOFreightDetailExt>();
                    if (invoiceExt != null){
                       invoiceExt.TrackNumber = track.TrackNumber;

                    }  
                    }

                }

    }
    #endregion
  }
```

DAC Extension:

```
public class SOFreightDetailExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOFreightDetail>
  {
    #region TrackNumber
    public abstract class trackNumber : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _TrackNumber;

    [PXString()]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tracking Number", IsReadOnly = true)]
    public virtual string TrackNumber
    {
      get
      {
        return this._TrackNumber;
      }
      set
      {
        this._TrackNumber = value;
      }
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

I want all tracking numbers associated with the Shipment Nbr to be displayed in this field, right now it only shows one. This only will happen if there is multiple packages for one shipment number.

Comment: what is the question/issue?

Comment: I want all tracking numbers associated with the Shipment Nbr to be displayed in this field, right now it only shows one. This only will happen if there is multiple packages for one shipment number. Added this question to the end of the original post.

Comment: you need to put the PXSelect in a foreach and append the string to the field. That should do it. And i dont see any need for the connection scope

Comment: I don't fully understand the foreach statement use in Acumatica, can you please provide an example? Mainly just what the second argument in my case would be, foreach(string nbr in ?).

Comment: looping through records in Acumatica via a PXSelect like so foreach(var row in PXSelect<...>.Select(myGraph, ...)). You should do this for your PXSelect on SOPackageDetail as right now you are just getting 1 record by that call NOT being in a foreach.

Comment: posted example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop on your records (PXSelect) in a foreach. You then need to add each string value to your tracknumber field. Something like this should work...

```
SOFreightDetailExt invoiceExt = row.GetExtension<SOFreightDetailExt>();
if(invoiceExt == null)
    return;
foreach(SOPackageDetail track in PXSelect<SOPackageDetail, Where<SOPackageDetail.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOFreightDetail.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(Base, row.ShipmentNbr))
{
    invoiceExt.TrackNumber = $"{invoiceExt.TrackNumber}, {track.TrackNumber}";
}
```

Also, there is no need for the PXConnectionScope. You can remove that.

Comment: Removed ConnectionScope and I'm getting the error Unexpected Token Error for the $.

Comment: Swap the string interpolation for string format or another string concatenate method.